# Is there a way to remove specific rows which contain specific string "X"

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a data-set in one column and I want to delete specific rows which contain specific text, lets say "Substitution:"

Is there a way to do this task all at once?

[image]

Comment: Just use a filter to either hide those rows or select those rows for deletion.